# Creating incrementing integer values for each file

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on program which generates error codes per file. 
Error codes need to start from zero and increment onwards, a file can contain 'n' error codes.

I tried with **COUNTER** macro but it seems it is not working per file basis and is being incremented globally.

If there a way I can reset **COUNTER** to zero for each file?

```
// a.cpp
int a_error1 = GetErrorCode(); // error1 = 0
int a_error2 = GetErrorCode(); // error2 = 1
int a_error3 = GetErrorCode(); // error3 = 2
int a_error4 = GetErrorCode(); // error4 = 3
```

Similarly

```
// b.cpp
int b_error1 = GetErrorCode(); // error1 = 0
int b_error2 = GetErrorCode(); // error2 = 1
int b_error3 = GetErrorCode(); // error3 = 2
int b_error4 = GetErrorCode(); // error4 = 3
```

I do not want to have something like

```
// a.cpp
int a_error1 = 0 
int a_error2 = 1 
int a_error3 = 2 
int a_error4 = 3
```

As this is error prone and can contain duplicate values.

**In summary the question would be: How do I generate incremental int values, starting from zero for each file?**

Comment: What is COUNTER macro? Without more information, you question is too broad to answer.

Comment: ```static int counter = 0; #define FILE_COUNTER (++counter)``` ?

Comment: One thing that is not clear from this question: is GetErrorCode() supposed to be evaluated at runtime or compile time? If it's okay for it to be runtime then it could be simply `static int GetErrorCode(const char * s) { static std::map<std::string, int> counters; return ++counters[s]; }` and you can make a macro `#define GET_ERROR_CODE GetErrorCode(__FILE__)` which you can use anywhere. If it needs to be done at compile time its more work but still possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is essentially an enumeration:

```
enum a_error {
    a_error1, // value will be 0
    a_error2, // 1
    a_error3, // ...
    a_error4
};
```

Consider if a scoped enumeration would be better for your design.

Comment: I just used this as an example, but the error code is an object containing many values which cannot be set as an enumeration.

Comment: I see. Well, if the error codes are not integral, then an enumeration by itself won't work. Please, add the new information to your question.